# Using Different Test Runners For Different Tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, dagger-2

I am using `Dagger 2` and trying to provide different dependencies at test time.

I can provide different dependencies for the tests but unfortunately, these then apply to all tests in the `androidTest` directory.

I do this by specifying a `TestAppComponent` which uses a `TestAppModule`. In my `TestApplication`, which extends my `AndroidApplication`, I supply the `TestAppComponent` rather than the real `AppComponent`. Then I have `TestRunner` that extends the `newApplication` method like so:

```
@Override
public Application newApplication(ClassLoader cl, String className, Context context) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
    return super.newApplication(cl, TestApplication.class.getName(), context);
}
```

Then to use this runner I replace the current runner with the following:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "com.company.myapp.TestRunner"
```

**My Question**

How do I use a different component/application/test runner for different tests rather than use the same for each one? I may want to mock a dependency in one test but not in another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this in a blog post. It bypasses creating a custom runner and instead uses a `Rule` to set a different component within the loaded `Application`. This means you can supply different components for each test class which is what I wanted to do.

The blog post by the guys at Ribot Labs can be found [here](https://labs.ribot.co.uk/fast-and-reliable-ui-tests-on-android-17c261b8220c#.lxor4oha6)